# bash print only last 7 fields

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I have hundreds of thousands of files with several hundreds of thousands of lines in each of them.

```
2022-09-19/SALES_1.csv:CUST1,US,2022-09-19,43.31,17.56,47.1,154.48,154. 114
2022-09-20/SALES_2.csv:CUST2,NA,2022-09-20,12.4,16.08,48.08,18.9,15.9,3517
```

The lines may have different number of fields. NO matter how many fields are present, I'm wanting to extract just the last 7 fields.

I'm trying with cut & awk but, have been only able to prit a range of fields but not last 'n' fields.

Please could I request guidance.

Comment: please update the question with your `awk` attempts, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: do all files have a field delimiter of a comma? for the sample input, is that a typo in the last field of the first line: `154. 114` (embedded space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$  rev file | cut -d, -f1-7 | rev
```

will give the last 7 fields regardless of varying number of fields in each record.

Answer (score 2):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -F',' 'NF>7{sub("([^,]*,){"NF-7"}","")} 1' file
US,2022-09-19,43.31,17.56,47.1,154.48,154. 114
2022-09-20,12.4,16.08,48.08,18.9,15.9,3517
```

Comment: Why is my output different from yours?

Comment: idk as I don't know what output you're getting but the most likely reason would be that the input you're using now is different from the input I'm using which is the input you provided in your question. Add the expected output to your question and the output you're getting so we can help you debug.

Comment: FWIW the currently accepted answer produces exactly the same output as my script when run against the same sample input you provided.

Comment: Hm, I just get unchanged output. I can see `NF>7` evaluates to `true` - when I add a `print` to `{}`, I get the lines printed twice. I'm running mawk.

Comment: Old versions of mawk (aka `mawk 1`) aren't POSIX-compliant as I said is needed. They were minimal-featured and designed for execution speed over functionality so, for example, I doubt if regexp intervals like `{n}` would be supported. You should get a modern awk, e.g. gawk.

Comment: Yes, I checked that, it's `mawk 1.3.4 20200120`, and the man page says "mawk conforms to the POSIX 1003.2  (draft  11.3)". Anyways, I guess, that's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
 1  {m,g}awk' BEGIN { _+=(_+=_^= FS = OFS = ",")+_
 2                   ___= "^[^"(__= "\5") ("]*")__
 3
 4  } NF<=_ || ($(NF-_) = __$(NF-_))^(sub(___,"")*!_)'
```

> 

```
US,
    2022-09-19,
    43.31,
    17.56,
    47.1,
    154.48,
    154. 114
2022-09-20,
    12.4,
    16.08,
    48.08,
    18.9,
    15.9,
    3517
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure Bash, without any external processes and/or pipes:

```bash
(IFS=,; while read -ra line; do printf '%s\n' "${line[*]: -7}"; done;) < file
```

Answer (score 1):

Prints the last 7 fields:

```
sed -E 's/.*,((.*,){6}.*)/\1/' file
```